# JavaScript fetch failed API call to servicedesk plus

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, http-status-code-400

I am trying to create a fetch call to servicedesk plus system but I keep getting 400 error, I understand that the request I made is not what the server wanted but in postman, I do manage to send that same query successfully. I can't understand what is the problem.

In the dev tools network tab I see this data after sending the JSON:

> response_status: {status_code: 4000,…}
> messages: [{status_code: 4001, field: "input_data", type: "failed", message: "JSON cant be analyzed"}]
> 0: {status_code: 4001, field: "input_data", type: "failed", message: "JSON cant be analyzed"}
> field: "input_data"
> message: "JSON cant be analyzed"
> status_code: 4001
> type: "failed"
> status: "failed"
> status_code: 4000

From what I read in the API documentation I saw that the 4001 error means that the ID or the name are not as they are in the service desk system.
here is a link to the [API docs](https://ui.servicedeskplus.com/APIDocs3/index.html#common-error-codes).

This is my code:

```
const jss = {
    "request": {
        "subject": "test 29072020",
        "description": "TEST REQUEST BY DAVID",
        "requester": {
            "id": "1231",
            "name": "david"
        },
    
    "resolution": {
        "content": "Mail Fetching Server problem has been fixed"
    },
    "status": {
        "name": "פתוחה"
    },
  "template": {
            "name": "Test for API",
            "id": "123123"
        },
    }
}
        const sendToSd = document.getElementById('send');
        sendToSd.addEventListener('click', submitData);
   
    var mydata = JSON.parse(jss);
    var stringify = JSON.stringify(mydata);
  

    async function submitData(){
       
        const url = 'http://MYURL.COM/api/v3/requests?TECHNICIAN_KEY=SOME-STRING&input_data='+stringify+'&FORMAT=json';
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
            
        });
        console.log('response',response)

    }
```

**This fetch works and manages to retrieve the data from the service desk using the same URL and TECHNICIAN_KEY.**

```
// fetch('http://MYURL.COM/api/v3/requests/61627?TECHNICIAN_KEY=SOME-STRING', {
//         method: 'GET'
//         })
//     .then(response => {
//         console.log(response);
//         return response;
//     });
```

Comment: post request doesnt work without body, send an empty object as body value

Comment: tried this:
`            const response = await fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                body: {}
                
            });`
the same result, am I doing it ok?

Comment: use content-type: 'application/json'

Comment: Tried this: 
const response = await fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: {}
                
            });

still same error... 4001. any more suggestions? please...

Comment: From backend Take body from "request body" instead from url and check if you are still facing this issue. as i found from your question issue is regarding "input_data" json

Comment: you mean something tike this?

   async function submitData(){
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: {
                    'TECHNICIAN_KEY': 'sdasdadasdas',
                    'input_data': JSON.stringify(mydata),
                    'FORMAT': 'json'
                }
                
            });
       

I receive a 400 error that the  TECHNICIAN_KEY is not recognized by the system

Comment: use like this body: JSON.stringify(data)